# Place 4 notorious problems into 2 diagrams (one assuming P=NP, and the other one assuming P!=NP)

Tags: p-vs-np

This diagram is on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete):

[image: On left side we see NP-hard intersecting NP class (assuming P!=NP), on right side we see NP-hard including NP (assuming P=NP)]

On left side we see NP-hard intersecting NP class (assuming P!=NP), on right side we see NP-hard including NP (assuming P=NP)

Where should I place the following problems (assume decisional part)?

- Traveling salesman
- Subset sum problem
- Sorting a list (any problem known to be solvable and verifiable in Polinomial time)
- Hanoi Towers

I'm a bit confused because I've seen many versions of those diagrams (I'm not even sure those are correct right now).

Comment: What is the decision problem associated with the Towers of Hanoi? Wikipedia give the complexity of all the other problems so what are you confused about that's stopping you answer the question yourself? If your confusion is with the underlying concepts, our [reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9556/9550) may be helpful.

Comment: The first two are NP-complete, the decision version of the third is in P, and the fourth is not a decision problem so doesn't fit in the diagram.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for being confused. I'm reading it right now